# MinMax in tic-tac-toe in c++

Tags: c++

The minmax algorithm returns an incorrect value during debugging, it does not set the value of the best move for me, worked in both Visual Studio 2008. Object-written program

opponent - circle

player - cross

checkWin - checks if there is a win / lose / draw

isMoveLeft - checks if you can make a move on the board
Here's the code:

```
 int GameState::minimax(Board& board,int length, int width, int depth, bool isMax)
{
    int score = checkWin(board,length,width);

    // If Maximizer has won the game return his/her 
    // evaluated score 
    if (score == 10)
        return score;

    // If Minimizer has won the game return his/her 
    // evaluated score 
    if (score == -10)
        return score;

    // If there are no more moves and no winner then 
    // it is a tie 
    if (isMovesLeft(board,length,width) == false)
        return 0;

    // If this maximizer's move 
    if (isMax)
    {
        int bestScore = -INFINITY;

        // Traverse all cells 
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                // Check if cell is empty 
                if (board.getBoard()[i][j].getStatus() == PUSTE_POLE)
                {
                    // Make the move 
                    board.getBoard()[i][j].setStatus(opponent);

                    // Call minimax recursively and choose 
                    // the maximum value 
                    int best = minimax(board,length,width, depth + 1, false);

                    // Undo the move 
                    board.getBoard()[i][j].setStatus(PUSTE_POLE);
                    bestScore = std::max(best, bestScore);
                }
            }
        }
        return bestScore;
    }

    // If this minimizer's move 
    else
    {
        int bestScore = INFINITY;
        // Traverse all cells 
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                // Check if cell is empty 
                if (board.getBoard()[i][j].getStatus() == PUSTE_POLE)
                {
                    // Make the move 
                    board.getBoard()[i][j].setStatus(player);

                    // Call minimax recursively and choose 
                    // the minimum value 
                    int best = minimax(board,length,width, depth + 1, true);

                    // Undo the move 
                    board.getBoard()[i][j].setStatus(PUSTE_POLE);
                    bestScore = std::min(best, bestScore);

                }
            }
        }
        return bestScore;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: *The minmax algorithm returns an incorrect value during debugging* -- So when debugging, what did you observe that would cause the behavior?  If you don't know, then you really were not debugging your program, only running it and reporting the final results.  Debugging means stepping through the program, observing which code path is taken, the value of variables, and then seeing if the program is taking the same path that follows your design.  If not, then you know what went wrong and you then make plans in fixing the issue.

Comment: The algorithm returns zero all the time, does not change its value in any step, and should, because it goes recursively through the entire game tree

Comment: Which causes a violation of access rights, because the set values in bestMove (-1, -1) are outside the range of the array - they are not changed, because the condition is not met

Comment: *, and should, because it goes recursively through the entire game tree* -- ok.  So you know the computer is doing exactly as you instructed, so your steps are not correct somewhere.

Comment: I check and look, I just don't see any error in the logic of this algorithm, which I implemented

Comment: *I check and look* -- Do not just "check and look".   Step through your code using the debugger -- you have a test case, so simply step one line at a time to see where your program is taking a path, a variable not set correctly, etc. where you didn't expect it to occur.  The computer does not have a mind of its own.  There are bugs in your program, but you are not putting in enough effort in fixing them.  Since you didn't post a [mcve], that is all that can be suggested.